# jquery how to remove scroll bar in background when select is expanded,background :none doesnt works

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#keyword_select").mouseover(function(){
    $("#keyword_select").css("height","200px","background-image","none").show(1000);

 });
 });

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#keyword_select").mouseout(function(){
     $("#keyword_select").css("height","20px").show(1000);
 });
 });
```

the css

```
#keyword_select {
height:23px;
width:200px;
background-image:url(ddl.jpg);
background-position:right;
background-repeat:no-repeat;

}
```

and the html

```
<select id=#keyword_select multiple="multiple">
<option> first image </option>
<option> second image</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please enter your question also in the body and not only in the title and try to be more clear about what you want

Comment: What scroll bar are you referring to? If something has a scrollbar, you can always control whether it appears using an overflow: hidden; css rule, but I'm not really clear on what it is you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The parent container should have

```
overflow:hidden;
```

Here is a bit more information on the topic [W3School Overflow](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_overflow.asp)